# Ubuntu 22.04.3 not recognizing hdmi port after yesterday's update

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, hdmi, monitor

I am using a Dell g15 with Nvidia graphics card.
Until yesterday, it was working fine with the open-source drivers. But after some updates it just won't recognize the HDMI port anymore.

`ubuntu-drivers devices` updates nothing.

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` did nothing as well.

xrabdr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
```

Software & Updates shows:

```
No aditional drivers available
```

inxi shows:

```
Device-2: NVIDIA GA107BM [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] driver: nouveau
```

Note that I have always used nouveau and this never happened.